# c++: more small files or fewer large files?

Tags: c++, performance, file, file-access

I have written a c++ prog to query a 100 GB dictionary. I have split the dictionary into n number of files of equal size. All split-files are placed in the same dir. The dictionary is fully indexed, i.e., once a query comes I know which spit-file to open and where to seek. My question is for better performance, which split will be better:
(a) Small number of large files or (b) Large number of small files?
Also, what would be an ideal split?

Comment: Ideally you would use indexed tables in a properly implemented database. Look at SQLite for example, that can be embedded within your own C++ code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a direct answer to that question. only experimenting can tell you. The cost of opening a file for read should be constant regardless of the size, reading the contents of the file is then of course dependant on the file size.

There are other hints though
I will assume that when you get a query, you open the file, parse/read it completly or until you find the word then close the file and return the result, in this case there are many enhancements to do, maybe you have them, maybe not, but here goes

1. If you get alot of queries, opening files can be expensive, in this
   case you might need to cache your files, or your search queries for
   better performance
2. When you open a file and read it, you are doing so sequentially, and this means that more or less the file is being loaded into the memory, I came once across a sax xml parser for java, which is able to load only the desired chunks of xml into memory, for handling really huge xml files, maybe there's somehing similar for c++. [SAX project](http://www.saxproject.org/)

check [when is a file loaded into memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132737/when-is-the-file-loaded-into-memory-for-fread-fopen-and-fwrite-calls)

A total different approach would be to use a database with index. this problem you don't have to deal with file opening problems

Comment: Thank you. "The cost of opening a file for read should be constant regardless of the size" was useful - this means that split size should not matter. I will experimentally check it though. The code does not read a file sequentially; it does a seek operation as it is known where exactly in the file the information related to a query term is present.

Comment: yes, but dependant on the OS and the function used to open, the timing at which the file will be loaded into the memory is different.

Comment: The cost of opening a file for read should be independent of the file size, but it will not be independent of the directory content of each directory in the file path (beginning with root). Of course the difference is negligible for reasonable directories. That is you should not see a difference when opening a file in a directory with 10 files and in a directory with 100 files. But in a directory with a million files things will get slow.

Comment: Also note that caching by both the drive (hardware), the device driver (think sata here) and the file system driver (think NTFS, ext3 etc.), will make things different depending on whether you are doing 'first access' or multiple accesses. In terms of performance and resources I'd say a single file should give best performance with minimal resource usage (you open it once, so no time to reopen it at all). If you have indexes that becomes one file for data and one for each index (open everything once). That is assuming your data may change. If it's static, just use a single file for everything.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. The suggestion to keep the dir less loaded is useful.

Answer (score 1):

Is your dictionary static or can it change at runtime?

If it's static use a single file for everything.

If it's dynamic and your indexes are "vectors" (not the best idea) use a file for data and one file for each index.

If it's dynamic and your indexes are "trees" (including deques and other vector like ADTs which are not 100% contiguous) you can use a single file again, unless it makes sense, for speed, to store indexes on separate volumes.

You should open the file at the beginning and never incur file open/close penalties any more.

If your application is 64 bit just map the whole file in memory and let the OS do the rest.

If your application is 32 bit, still use memory mapping to access the file. You'll need to create a memory mapped "window" for each possible concurrent access you may need to do (for static data, likely one per thread on the data, one or two per thread on each index).