# Is the content of a text file open with fopen() will be in the stack?

Tags: c, memory

I have this piece of code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    FILE *lol = fopen("/some_folder/lol", "rt");
```

And i would like to know where in the memory will go the content of the file "lol".

Thanks

Comment: Mainly the `fopen` function return a file descriptor, does not allocate the whole content of file. You have to use `fread` to get the content of file.

Comment: the content? you haven't read anything.

Comment: After your edit: `buffer` must be allocated statically or dynamically. `fgets` does not allocate memory for it. Take a look at t[this example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm)

Comment: Side note: you must check the functions return values.

Comment: Please don't edit questions so as to invalidate existing answers, it's very unfriendly and annoying.

Answer (score 0):

When you open a file - it doesn't load the file, it actually opens a handle to the file - for reference. Once open, you can then read the file using fread command.

This is answered here -

[When is the file loaded into memory - for fread, fopen and fwrite calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132737/when-is-the-file-loaded-into-memory-for-fread-fopen-and-fwrite-calls)