# C - Reading file content even after the file is deleted

Tags: c

Check this program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()  {
    FILE* f;
    char x[100];
    f = fopen("a.txt","r");

    int a = remove("a.txt");

    sleep(5);
    fgets(x,100,f);
    printf("Remove() : %d\nFile Content : %s\n",a,x);

    printf("fclose() : %d\n",fclose(f));
    return 0;
}
```

In the above code, the file is deleted even before reading the content. But still it works and close the file successfully with status 0.

**Output**

```
$ echo hello > a.txt
$ gcc a.c && ./a.out

Remove() : 0
File Content : hello

fclose() : 0
```

Comment: Because all data has load on the RAM, so delete file will no cause any trouble ~

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132737/when-is-the-file-loaded-into-memory-for-fread-fopen-and-fwrite-calls Read answer by Alexander Pavlov.. it says `fopen()` only creates a handle to the file.

Comment: What is your query/issue, what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Just want to know why it is possible to do this.

Comment: if you want to delete file before you read or open you need to call `remove` before `open`. current implementation the content of file already in RAM, so its expected behavior.

Comment: @ThiruShetty `fopen` does not load the file into ram.

Comment: @Pzy64 to get rid of userspace caching you need to use `open`, not `fopen` (and `read`, ...). Still, it is OS dependent. On unix systems it is perfectly ok because remove (actually, `unlink`) only breaks link between given filename and file contents, and contents may still be reachable by other means (still open file descriptors or other filename).

Answer (score 3):

It's OS/implementation dependent. On Linux, the file is actually "pending for deletion", meaning that since the file is opened, the kernel "waits" for the file to be closed before to actually free the space taken by the file.

Doing `lsof`  (maybe extend the `sleep` to give you time to do that)

```
lsof | grep file
```

shows that your program processes maintains the file opened ([lsof man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/lsof)).

Answer (score 1):

Deleting a file does not necessarily actually "remove" it. The things that happen is that the reference to the file is destroyed. It is a bit like pointers. You can compare your code to this:

```
void delete(int ** ptr)
{
    *ptr=NULL;
}

int main()
{
    int a=5;
    int p1=&a;
    int p2=&a;
    delete(p1);  // Pretty much equivalent to deleting a file
    printf("a: %d\n", *p1);  // We can still access it through a another pointer
}
```